# RootRecord does not set data version to DATA_VERSION

Tags: quip, liveapps

According to the [Quip Live Apps Reference](https://quip.com/dev/liveapps/documentation#record-data-version), setting `DATA_VERSION` on a `Record` class will set a default data version for new instances of that record type:

> **quip.apps.Record.DATA_VERSION**
>
> Optional static field that defines the data version that new Records of this type should be created with.

However, this is not true for `RootRecord` itself, which always gets initialized with data version == 0. Demonstrating this point is a small Quip Live App, where both `RootRecord` and a child record have `DATA_VERSION` set to 2, yet only the child record's data version was set to 2.

Here is the code showing record initialization:

```js
class RootRecord extends quip.apps.RootRecord {
    static getProperties = () => ({
        child: ChildRecord,
    });

    static getDefaultProperties = () => ({
        child: {},
    });

    static DATA_VERSION = 2;
}

quip.apps.registerClass(RootRecord, 'root-record');

class ChildRecord extends quip.apps.Record {
    static getProperties = () => ({});

    static DATA_VERSION = 2;
} 

quip.apps.registerClass(ChildRecord, 'child-record');
```

---

***Is this discrepancy a bug, or intended behavior?***

---

## Workaround

Though `RootRecord` always initializes itself with data version == 0, it *is possible* to override it post-creation using `rootRecord.setDataVersion()`. With this, a full workaround for this issue is to add this code to `initializationCallback`:

```js
if (params.isCreation) {
    quip.apps.getRootRecord().setDataVersion(RootRecord.DATA_VERSION);
}
```

## Live App Example

A fully-functioning live app demonstrating everything in this post can be found at https://github.com/mxxk/quip-live-app-record-data-version.

### Features

- Shows that `RootRecord` has data version set to 0
- Provides a way to manually increment it
- Includes above workaround

### Screenshot

[image: quip live app]